# j2me-j2se socket connection

Tags: sockets, java-me, wifi, midp

I am working on a j2me application that sends data to PC over WiFi using Sockets. What should be the server address? i.e. What should I use instead of 'localhost' in the code below?

Client Code(j2me):

```
SocketConnection sc = (SocketConnection)
Connector.open("socket://localhost:9002");
DataOutputStream os = null;
try{
    os = sc.openDataOutputStream();
    os.writeUTF("Test Dama");
} finally{
  sc.close();
  os.close();
}
```

Server Code(j2se):

```
    ServerSocket echoServer = null;
    String line;
    DataInputStream is;

    Socket clientSocket = null;

    try {
       echoServer = new ServerSocket(9002);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
       System.out.println(e);
    }
    try {
       clientSocket = echoServer.accept();
       is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

       line = is.readUTF();

       System.out.println("Received:"+line);

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
       System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on the ip/domain of the server.

If you are running things on a local network (in your home/office) then just find out what is the ip of the machine running the server code.
In linux systems you can find that with the command *ifconfig*, then in the output the ip address is under *inet addr*.  In windows systems use *ipconfig /all*.

Once you have the ip of the machine running the server, just put that instead of the *localhost* that you are using in the client.

If you want this to work on the public network though, you'll have to run the server code on a machine that has a [static ip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#Uses_of_static_addressing) (or use [dynamic DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS)).